# Time dependent workflow to send chatter notification on contract expire

Tags: time-dependent-workflow

I want to send chatter feed notification and create task with the help of time dependent workflow. Condition is, I have one formula field on contract which calculates notification days of contract.

1. If send_notification checkbox is true and notification_days__c=120 then add chatter feed before 120 days on account page and create task.
2. If  send_notification checkbox is false and notification_days__c=180 then add chatter feed on account page and create task before 180 days .

Will you please help me in creating this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could divide this implementation in 2 parts.

1. Using workflow flow rule to send time-dependent action like creating task and update an indicator in Contract record lets say "fireTimebasedFlow" boolean to `true`.

Be sure to select "Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change" checkbox in field update.

2. Create a Process Builder process on Contract Object when `fireTimebasedFlow = true` and define action 'Post to chatter'.

Refer this [Use Process Builder to Post to Chatter](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/projects/workshop-electric-imp/steps/chatter-post) trailhead for more details

Comment: Thanks Santanu for reply. I tried the given solution. But after workflow execution my task is creating and field is also updating to true. but then process builder is not executing. If i edit the task manuaaly then process builder is executing. Can you please help.

Comment: In workflow field update you will have an option to select a checkbox to run the workflows which are met due to this field update. please try that option.

Comment: Sunny has mentioned correctly, you need to select that checkbox at workflow field update. Updated my ans